# How to convert space-delimited .txt File to ","-delimited .txt file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I do have a text file as below:

***Employee details.txt***

```
Raja Palit     77489  24   84   12/12/2011
Mathew bargur  77559  25   88   01/12/2011
harin Roy      77787  24   80   12/12/2012
Soumi paul      77251  24   88   11/11/2012
```

I want the file as below:

***Expected file:***

```
Raja,Palit,77489,24,84,12/12/2011
Mathew,bargur,77559,25,88,01/12/2011
harin,Roy,77787,24,80,12/12/2012
Soumi,paul,77251,24,88,11/11/2012
```

What I tried below:

```
IO.foreach('D://docs//details.txt') do |line|
  splits = line.split("\t")

  col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = splits


  splits[6..-1].join(',')
end
```

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings come with a `squeeze` method, it squeezes runs of the char(s) in the argument into one char. In this case it reduces the multiple spaces into one space, which is then replaced by a comma:

```
File.open("test.txt") do |in_file|
  File.open("test.csv", 'w') do |out_file| #the 'w' opens the file for writing
    in_file.each {|line| out_file << line.squeeze(' ').gsub(' ', ',') }
  end # closes test.csv
end # closes test.txt
```

Comment: @VMSlover, don't ask for up votes please. Ask good questions, and provide good answers. If you can't do those things then expect what you get.

Comment: `line.squeeze(' ').gsub(' ', ',')` can be reduced to `line.gsub(/ +/, ',')`.

Comment: @steenslag, you actually do have an error in your code. Took me a while to find it. In your third line you have `in_file.each do {|line| out_file << line.squeeze(' ').gsub(' ', ',') }`. You are mixing together the two different block formats. If you remove the `do` then the solution functions.

Answer (score 6):

Though it seems like a quick way to deal with this sort of data by splitting on whitespace, that will fail if any field contains embedded whitespace. For instance, if the name of the person in the record is something like "Maria Von Trapp" or "Smokey the Bear", the resulting comma-delimited fields will be wrong.

The correct way to deal with this is to parse based on column-field widths, then squeeze and strip whitespace inside those fields, then turn the record into a CSV record.

```
require 'csv'
require 'scanf' if (RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3')

FORMAT = '%15c %d %d %d %10c'

data = <<EOT
Raja Palit      77489  24   84   12/12/2011
Mathew bargur   77559  25   88   01/12/2011
harin Roy       77787  24   80   12/12/2012
Soumi paul      77251  24   88   11/11/2012
Maria Von Trapp 99999  99   99   12/31/2012
Smokey the Bear 99999  99   99   12/31/2012
EOT

data.split("\n").each do |li|
  fields = li.scanf(FORMAT)
  puts [fields.first.strip, *fields[1 .. -1]].to_csv
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Raja Palit,77489,24,84,12/12/2011
Mathew bargur,77559,25,88,01/12/2011
harin Roy,77787,24,80,12/12/2012
Soumi paul,77251,24,88,11/11/2012
Maria Von Trapp,99999,99,99,12/31/2012
Smokey the Bear,99999,99,99,12/31/2012
```

Note, Ruby 1.9.3 split `scanf` into its own module, which explains the conditional require.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to replace any whitespace characters with a comma:

```
my_string.sub! /\s/g, ','
```

If you want to discard empty fields, you could use this:

```
my_string.sub! /\s+/g, ','
```

An alternative would be to split it on spaces and join on commas. This will also discard empty fields:

```
my_string = my_string.split(' ').join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open("details.txt", "r+"){|io| io.write(io.read.gsub(/[ \t]+/, ","))}
```